# using express csurf with ajax doesnt work

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

i am new with node js. i try to use csurf token with express using AJAX. here is my code

from server (app.js)

```
      var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
      var csrf = require('csurf')
      var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
      var express = require('express')

      // setup route middlewares
      var csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true })
      var parseForm = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

      // create express app
      var app = express()
      app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
      app.set('views', 'views')

      // parse cookies
      // we need this because "cookie" is true in csrfProtection
      app.use(cookieParser())
      app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

      app.get('/form', csrfProtection, function (req, res) {
      // pass the csrfToken to the view
      res.render('send', { csrfToken: req.csrfToken() })
      })

      app.post('/process', parseForm, csrfProtection, function (req, res) {
        console.log(req.body.name); // <--- it is doesnt show in my terminal
        res.send('data is being processed')
      })

      app.listen(3000);
```

HTML (send.ejs)

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta name="csrf-token" content="<%=csrfToken%>">
      <title>Document</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="Jhon Doe" class="inp-name">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn-send">
        </form>
        <script src="/javascripts/script.js"></script>    
      </body>
      </html>
```

JS file (script.js)

```
       document.querySelector('.btn-send').addEventListener('click',            

       () => {
       const name  = document.querySelector('.inp-name').value;

       // Read the CSRF token from the <meta> tag
       const token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-                      
                      token"]').getAttribute('content')

       // Make a request using the Fetch API
       fetch('/process', {
       credentials: 'same-origin', // <-- includes cookies in the request
       headers: {
        'CSRF-Token': token // <-- is the csrf token as a header
       },
       method: 'POST',
       body: {
        name: name
       }
       })

       });
```

when i try to run this i think it doesnt work because when i see in my terminal the name of Jhon Doe doesnt appears.
i try this example from this site http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/csurf.html

Comment: add app.use(bodyParse.json()) before /process route in backend code

Comment: Hy Abhay thx for reply for the parser form i think i already added in this code    var parseForm = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }) then   app.post('/process', parseForm, csrfProtection, function (req, res) {
        console.log(req.body.name); // <--- it is doesnt show in my terminal
        res.send('data is being processed')
      })